# Python importing a text file and converting string to float

Tags: python, string, import, floating, txt

I have encountered some value error when input txt file into python.

the txt file called "htwt.txt", and contain the below data:

```
Ht Wt

169.6 71.2

166.8 58.2

157.1 56

181.1 64.5

158.4 53

165.6 52.4

166.7 56.8

156.5 49.2

168.1 55.6

165.3 77.8
```

When I typed the below code, and value errors are occurred.

```
import numpy as np

import pandas as pd

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

import os


import statsmodels.api as sm

from statsmodels.formula.api import ols


os.chdir("/Users/James/Desktop/data/")

data1=np.loadtxt("htwt.txt") 

df1=pd.DataFrame(data1)
```

> ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'Ht'

May I know what should the correct code so that it can be converted to the data frame? thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Pandas `read_csv` is enough

```
import pandas as pd
import os
os.chdir("/Users/James/Desktop/data/")

df1 = pd.read_csv("htwt.txt",sep=' ')
```

Output:

```
>>> df1
      Ht    Wt
0  169.6  71.2
1  166.8  58.2
2  157.1  56.0
3  181.1  64.5
4  158.4  53.0
5  165.6  52.4
6  166.7  56.8
7  156.5  49.2
8  168.1  55.6
9  165.3  77.8
```

Checking the types:

```
>>> df.info()
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 10 entries, 0 to 9
Data columns (total 2 columns):
 #   Column  Non-Null Count  Dtype  
---  ------  --------------  -----  
 0   Ht      10 non-null     float64
 1   Wt      10 non-null     float64
dtypes: float64(2)
memory usage: 288.0 bytes
```

Answer (score 1):

Like mentioned above pandas `read_csv` works, but if you insist on using `np.loadtxt` you can skip the first row which can't be converted to a float. You can do:

```py
data1 = np.loadtxt("htwt.txt", skiprows=1)
```

Comment: Please see OP's comment on Alexander's answer.

Answer (score 0):

The first row in your text file has alphanumeric characters: "Ht Wt".
These characters cannot be converted to a floating point number.
Remove the first row and you should be fine.

Comment: Hi Alexander, any ways that do not need to remove the first row but change them into column name when import them? thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

```py
#for skipping of the first line
file1 = open("hwwt.txt")

lines = file1.readlines()[1:]
for line in lines:
    print(line.rstrip())

OUTPUT
#otherwise you can use read_csv which is enough
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.